# How to remove the rest of the strings that are not enclosed by a tag

Tags: php, html

I have a string with inlineXML tags and I want to replace it with span and dump the rest of the rest of the strings that are not enclosed by the tags. Here's my code.

```
$string  = "My name is <Name>John Farro</Name>. I live in <Location>New York City<Location>."

$new = str_replace(array("<Name>", "</Name>", "<Location>", "</Location>"), array("<span style="color:blue">", "</span>", "<span style="color:red">", "</span>"), "$string");

echo $new;

Result: "My name is <span style="color:blue">John Farro</span>. I live in <span style="color:red">New York City</span>."
```

What I want is for it just to be like this:

```
<span style="color:blue">John Farro</span>
<span style="color:red">New York City</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use Regular Expressions to strip HTML tags

```
/<\s*span[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*\/\s*span>/
```

php code you need:

```
    <?php
        $str = 'My name is <span style="color:blue">John Farro</span>. I live in <span style="color:red">New York City</span>.';
        preg_match_all("/<\s*span[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*\/\s*span>/", $str, $matches);
        print_r($matches[0]);
    ?>
```

Result:

[image: Result]

references:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: @Leng Keng your regex is only working for java script not in php. :(